# Ajax stops working on $POST in my Controller, else it's working fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, post

I need to ask that I'm calling this function on Onchange event, it is working fine only when I don't ask it for $POST in the controller if I ask for $POST ajax request stops and nothing is return

if I //Comment these lines, my code returns something, on these lines, my ajax/ jquery request fails and I get nothing, it stops.
tried this

```
$list = $this->input->post("data");
```

tried this too

```
  $list = $_POST('data');
```

also tried this

```
 $list = json_decode($_POST('data'));
```

none of them working for me, I need to pass Array from this function and catch it through $POST on Controller Side

```
//javascript
function show_product(month,year) {
    var list = $('#customer').val();
    $.ajax({
        type  : 'POST',
        url   : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/BillController/PerdayCalculation/"+month+"/"+year,
        async : true,
        data: {'data':list},
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }     
    });
}
```

```
//controller
$list = $this->input->post("data");
```

I'm sending an array through this $POST, which I'm not able to catch at Controller side

Comment: Why you are concatenating month and year in the url? you cannot send parameters in post request.

Comment: can you share controller side full code, I mean whole `PerdayCalculation` function ?

Comment: `public function PerdayCalculation($month=null, $year = null) {              
       $list = json_decode($_POST('data'));                   
       $listz = $this->bill->CalculateBillsofMonth($month,$year,$list);
       echo json_encode($listz);
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below changes in your side, here I passed all your parameters in `POST`
and changed `base_url` to `site_url`
Ajax:

```
function show_product(month,year) {
    var listArray = $('#customer').val();
    var listString = listArray.toString();//if your listArray then do toString
    $.ajax({
        type  : 'POST',
        url   : "<?php echo site_url(); ?>index.php/BillController/PerdayCalculation/",
        async : true,
        data : ({list : listString,month : month,year : year}),
        //dataType : "json",
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }     
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
function PerdayCalculation(){
   $list = $this->input->post("list");
   $month = $this->input->post("month");
   $year = $this->input->post("year");
   echo $list.' => '.$month.' => '.$year;die;
}
```

> Once you get `$list` as comma separated then use `explode()` to convert as array and pass that array to `method chaining CI Query`

OR

> $list = "'" . implode( "','", explode(',',$list) ) . "'";

pass this `$list` to your query

Comment: tried this, its getting month and year but not getting list

Comment: Received month and year through POST but not getting the list..

```query: "SELECT `bill_date` as date, SUM(`buffalo_qty`) as buffaloqty, SUM(`cow_qty`) as cowqty, SUM(`yougurt_qty`) as yougurtqty FROM tbl_bill WHERE `bill_date` = '07/31/2019' and customer_id NOT IN ' ' "
list: null```

Comment: ```list:Array [ "117", "99" ]```
This is what I can see through F12 in the browser

Comment: thanks bro.. I was missing this ```listString = listArray.toString();```

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm $('#customer').val(); returns a value? Just place it in a simple alert function.
Also,
Hit F12 in your browser, go to network tab, try your action and see what data is sent to your server

Comment: #customer is a multiselect, I'm Selecting multiple customer's from there to be passed in the SQL Query to get the desired Results
it returns this:
`list:Array [ "117", "99" ]`